# AT command list as char * array

Tags: c++, c

,,I need to provide an AT command to a modem which looks like this: **AT^SRPN=1,99991,"Download_URL","Image";^SMSO**

How can I insert the variable download_url and the variable image into the commands string array? Is the right way to declare the commands array not as const and to use strcpy() to insert the two variables into the commands list?

The function at_send_commands() needs the commands list as const.
Function proto: `at_resp_t at_send_commands(TickType ticks_to_wait, const char *commands[]);`

```
at_resp_t at_send_download_url_and_image(const char *download_url, const char *image)
{
    static const char *commands[] = 
    {
        "AT^SRPN=1,99991,",
        download_url,
        ",",
        image,
        ";^SMSO\r",
        NULL
    };

    at_resp_t err = at_send_commands(AT_TIMEOUT, commands);
    if (err)
        return err;
}
```

Comment: Does your code not work? Is there an error you receive? The way you have written it, I don't think commands[] needs to be static. But that does not change much if the code already doesn't work. Also a prototype of at_send_commands() would be useful.

Comment: It most certainly *cannot* be static, since it depends on run-time values.

Comment: Ok, I understand...if I print the command in at_send_commands() I only see "AT^SRPN=1,99991,"

Comment: Ok based on the prototype I would question "," as being a command. Is there any help for that function that tells you how to format commands[]?

Comment: The commands list end must be NULL. In my description I already mentioned how the command must look like. The '\r' is the end character of the whole command.

Comment: You wrote how the command string must look at the end. But from your code it seems that at_send_commands() creates that string, since you input an array of strings. Maybe just try to make a single string for the whole command and put it into commands[] array.

Comment: This question is tagged C and C++.  Which one do you want the solution written in?

Comment: I would prefer only a C solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C the simplest way is IMO

```
void send_command(const char *download_url, const char *image) {
    char buf[1000];
    sprintf(buf, "AT^SRPN=1,99991,\"%s\",\"%s\";^SMSO",
            download_url, image);
    ...
}
```

in `buf` you will end up having the final command to send to the modem.

If this code can be used in an hostile environment then you should also pay attention that no overflow can happen when passed large strings as url/image (e.g. add a check on `strlen` first or use `snprintf` instead).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
at_resp_t at_send_download_url_and_image(const char *download_url, const char *image)
{
    std::string str("AT^SRPN=1,99991,");
    str += download_url;
    str += ",";
    str += image;
    str += ";^SMSO\r";

    const char* command = str.c_str();
    const char* commands[] = 
    {
        command,
        NULL
    };

    at_resp_t err = at_send_commands(AT_TIMEOUT, commands);

    if (err)
        return err;
}
```